# How to set Resource file path relative to the project file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resources

Let's say I have a directory A, and has a project file x.csproj and sln in that directory.
I also have resource file x.resources in it.

How can I set the resource file without the absolute path `C:\A\x.resources`, but relative path `.\x.resources`? I tried with `x.resources` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error does it give you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem.  My co-worker didn't even try to fix it in the UI but just hacked the CSPROJ file in a text editor:

**CSPROJ Path**: C:\foo\bar\SolutionNm\ProjectNm\ProjectNm.csproj

**Res Path**: C:\foo\bar\Icons.res

Original:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Win32Resource>C:\foo\bar\Icons.res</Win32Resource>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Modified:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Win32Resource>..\..\Icons.res</Win32Resource>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As long as you don't try to modify the value in the UI again, it won't complain

Cheers,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

I realize that the asker was using .NET, but just as an FYI, for C++ projects you have to edit your VCXPROJ file, and the resources are stored in a slightly different format near the bottom of the file.

Original:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Image Include="C:\projects\dragdroptree\DragDropView\res\bmp00001.bmp" />
    <Image Include="C:\projects\dragdroptree\DragDropView\res\toolbar1.bmp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Modified:

```
<ItemGroup>        
    <Image Include="res\toolbar.bmp" />
    <Image Include="res\bmp00001.bmp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Just to clarify, the paths you put in there are relative to the directory that the VCXPROJ file is in.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Visual Studio sometimes puts the `<PropertyGroup> <Win32Resource>` too early in the .csproj, so you would need to manually edit the XML and move the `<PropertyGroup>` after the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` element so the reference will be relative to the .csproj file.